# Entity framework generated query with not-exists column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

a have a table

```
CREATE TABLE AppUserInRole
(
    Id              BIGINT          NOT NULL    IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,                       
    IdAppUser       BIGINT          NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AppUser (Id),        
    IdAppUserRole   BIGINT          NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AppUserRole (Id),
    ValidFrom       DATETIME2       NOT NULL    DEFAULT GETDATE(),                          
    ValidTo         DATETIME2       NULL,                                                   
    CreatedDate     DATETIME2       NOT NULL    DEFAULT GETDATE(),                          
    CreatedBy       BIGINT  NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AppUser (Id),                                               
)
```

For generating i use EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator (http://www.reversepoco.com/).

This is my classes:

```
[Table("AppUserInRole", Schema = "dbo")]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator", "2.31.1.0")]
public partial class AppUserInRole
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(@"Id", Order = 1, TypeName = "bigint")]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)

    [Column(@"IdAppUser", Order = 2, TypeName = "bigint")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Id app user")]
    public long IdAppUser { get; set; } // IdAppUser

    [Column(@"IdAppUserRole", Order = 3, TypeName = "bigint")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Id app user role")]
    public long IdAppUserRole { get; set; } // IdAppUserRole

    [Column(@"ValidFrom", Order = 4, TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Valid from")]
    public System.DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Now; // ValidFrom

    [Column(@"ValidTo", Order = 5, TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [Display(Name = "Valid to")]
    public System.DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; } // ValidTo

    [Column(@"CreatedDate", Order = 6, TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Created date")]
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Now; // CreatedDate

    [Column(@"CreatedBy", Order = 7, TypeName = "bigint")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Created by")]
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; } // CreatedBy

    // Foreign keys

    /// <summary>
    /// Parent AppUser pointed by [AppUserInRole].([CreatedBy]) (FK__AppUserIn__Creat__1AD3FDA4)
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")] public virtual AppUser AppUser_CreatedBy { get; set; } // FK__AppUserIn__Creat__1AD3FDA4
    /// <summary>
    /// Parent AppUser pointed by [AppUserInRole].([IdAppUser]) (FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__30F848ED)
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("IdAppUser")] public virtual AppUser AppUser_IdAppUser { get; set; } // FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__30F848ED
    /// <summary>
    /// Parent AppUserRole pointed by [AppUserInRole].([IdAppUserRole]) (FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__31EC6D26)
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("IdAppUserRole")] public virtual AppUserRole AppUserRole { get; set; } // FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__31EC6D26
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator", "2.31.1.0")]
    public partial class AppUserInRoleConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<AppUserInRole>
    {
        public AppUserInRoleConfiguration()
            : this("dbo")
        {
        }

        public AppUserInRoleConfiguration(string schema)
        {
            Property(x => x.ValidTo).IsOptional();

            InitializePartial();
        }
        partial void InitializePartial();
    }
```

So I need to select data from this table method:

```
public async Task<List<AppUserInRole>> GetUserRoles(long userId, bool onlyValid)
        {
            var data = from d in DataContext.AppUserInRoles
                where d.IdAppUser == userId
                select d;

            if (onlyValid)
                data = data.Between(DateTime.Now, a => a.ValidFrom, a => a.ValidTo ?? DateTime.MaxValue);

            return await data.ToListAsync();
        }
```

When I call this method, the Entity Framework generates the following query:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[IdAppUser] AS [IdAppUser], 
    [Extent1].[IdAppUserRole] AS [IdAppUserRole], 
    [Extent1].[ValidFrom] AS [ValidFrom], 
    [Extent1].[ValidTo] AS [ValidTo], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Extent1].[AppUser_Id] AS [AppUser_Id], 
    [Extent1].[AppUser_Id1] AS [AppUser_Id1]
    FROM [dbo].[AppUserInRole] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[IdAppUser] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[ValidFrom] <= convert(datetime2, '2017-07-31 22:13:26.6862657', 121)) AND (convert(datetime2, '2017-07-31 22:13:26.6862657', 121) <= (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ValidTo] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__1 ELSE [Extent1].[ValidTo] END))
```

The Entity Framework throws following error: Invalid column name 'AppUser_Id'. Invalid column name 'AppUser_Id1'. The AppUser_Id and AppUser_Id1 columns are not really extinct. For what reason does it generate these columns?

Thank you very much for your advice and help.

Comment: What does your `AppUser` model look like?

Comment: Since you have the database, why not create a model after creating the table in the database? Use db first instead of code first

Comment: EBrown: The AppUser is a huge class. There is a reference in each application table (even in AppUser table) to AppUser table ID column (CreatedBy BIGINT  NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AppUser (Id)). And application has about 90 tables

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't repro using EF 6.1.3

```
create database foo
go
use foo
go
create table AppUser
(
 Id bigint primary key
)

create table AppUserRole
(
 Id bigint primary key
)

CREATE TABLE AppUserInRole
(
    Id              BIGINT          NOT NULL    IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,                       
    IdAppUser       BIGINT          NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AppUser (Id),        
    IdAppUserRole   BIGINT          NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AppUserRole (Id),
    ValidFrom       DATETIME2       NOT NULL    DEFAULT GETDATE(),                          
    ValidTo         DATETIME2       NULL,                                                   
    CreatedDate     DATETIME2       NOT NULL    DEFAULT GETDATE(),                          
    CreatedBy       BIGINT  NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AppUser (Id),                                               
)
```

And:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{

    public class AppUser
    {
        public long Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)
    }

    public class AppUserRole
    {
        public long Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)
    }

    [Table("AppUserInRole", Schema = "dbo")]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator", "2.31.1.0")]
    public partial class AppUserInRole
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column(@"Id", Order = 1, TypeName = "bigint")]
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Id")]
        public long Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)

        [Column(@"IdAppUser", Order = 2, TypeName = "bigint")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Id app user")]
        public long IdAppUser { get; set; } // IdAppUser

        [Column(@"IdAppUserRole", Order = 3, TypeName = "bigint")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Id app user role")]
        public long IdAppUserRole { get; set; } // IdAppUserRole

        [Column(@"ValidFrom", Order = 4, TypeName = "datetime2")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Valid from")]
        public System.DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Now; // ValidFrom

        [Column(@"ValidTo", Order = 5, TypeName = "datetime2")]
        [Display(Name = "Valid to")]
        public System.DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; } // ValidTo

        [Column(@"CreatedDate", Order = 6, TypeName = "datetime2")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created date")]
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Now; // CreatedDate

        [Column(@"CreatedBy", Order = 7, TypeName = "bigint")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created by")]
        public long CreatedBy { get; set; } // CreatedBy

        // Foreign keys

        /// <summary>
        /// Parent AppUser pointed by [AppUserInRole].([CreatedBy]) (FK__AppUserIn__Creat__1AD3FDA4)
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")] public virtual AppUser AppUser_CreatedBy { get; set; } // FK__AppUserIn__Creat__1AD3FDA4
                                                                                         /// <summary>
                                                                                         /// Parent AppUser pointed by [AppUserInRole].([IdAppUser]) (FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__30F848ED)
                                                                                         /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("IdAppUser")] public virtual AppUser AppUser_IdAppUser { get; set; } // FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__30F848ED
                                                                                         /// <summary>
                                                                                         /// Parent AppUserRole pointed by [AppUserInRole].([IdAppUserRole]) (FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__31EC6D26)
                                                                                         /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("IdAppUserRole")] public virtual AppUserRole AppUserRole { get; set; } // FK__AppUserIn__IdApp__31EC6D26
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator", "2.31.1.0")]
    public partial class AppUserInRoleConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<AppUserInRole>
    {
        public AppUserInRoleConfiguration()
            : this("dbo")
        {
        }

        public AppUserInRoleConfiguration(string schema)
        {
            Property(x => x.ValidTo).IsOptional();

            InitializePartial();
        }
        partial void InitializePartial();
    }
    class Db: DbContext
    {
        public Db(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AppUserInRole> AppUserInRoles { get; set; }

        public async Task<List<AppUserInRole>> GetUserRoles(long userId, bool onlyValid)
        {
            var data = from d in this.AppUserInRoles
                       where d.IdAppUser == userId
                       select d;

            if (onlyValid)
                data = data.Where(r => r.ValidFrom < DateTime.Now && (DateTime.Now < (r.ValidTo ?? DateTime.MaxValue)));

            return  await data.ToListAsync();
        }

    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {




            using (var db = new Db("Server=.;Database=foo;Integrated Security=true"))
            {
                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);


                var data = db.GetUserRoles(1, true).Result;

            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[IdAppUser] AS [IdAppUser],
    [Extent1].[IdAppUserRole] AS [IdAppUserRole],
    [Extent1].[ValidFrom] AS [ValidFrom],
    [Extent1].[ValidTo] AS [ValidTo],
    [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate],
    [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy]
    FROM [dbo].[AppUserInRole] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[IdAppUser] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[ValidFrom] < (SysDateTime())) AND ((SysDateTime()) < (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ValidTo] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__1 ELSE [Extent1].[ValidTo] END))
```

Comment: The same problem I have with other tables in app.